# Undefined variable: node

Tags: nodes

Im using

```
views_embed_view('view_name', 'view_block_name', $node->nid);
```

and im getting error Notice: Undefined variable: node in functin include()
So in D7 We cant use $node inside page.tpl.php?

Comment: The answer is theme dependent. What theme are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using drupal 7, there should already be a node object available when you are looking at a full node page. Looking at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7 - the default implementation embeds it into the $variables array:

```
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
```

If your theme is overriding this, you can simply add it back in.

An example might be:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
}
```

Comment: so as you said this error wouldnt appear at all? Im not overiding $node in my theme.

Comment: If your theme implements hook_preprocess_page() and fails to declare the $variables['node'] parameter then $node will be missing from page.tpl.php. Fortunately this is easy to rectify - see my code snippet above ;)